# gson NoSuchFieldException error

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm trying to convert a custom object to JSON and then save it to SharedPreferences. When I try to do that, the app crashes giving a `NoSuchFieldException` error.

Here's the code:

```
User myUser= new User("a", "b", 2, getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(myUser);
prefsEditor.putString(myUser.getUserPhone(), json);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

I think the problem lies at the `gson.toJson` conversion, because when I comment it the app doesn't crash anymore.

Any suggestion?  Thanks

***Logcat:***

```
   java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: ASCENDING
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$EnumTypeAdapter.<init>(TypeAdapters.java:791)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$30.create(TypeAdapters.java:817)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.create(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:53)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory.create(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:126)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:661)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:648)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:603)
```

Comment: `getApplicationContext() ` return app `context` which not ant data Type.

Comment: remove getApplicationContext() from `User` class  or write annotation @Export false.

Comment: you probably should not try to serialize a `Context`

Comment: I agree, I think removing the getApplicationContext from the object and its constructor is a good starting point. Unfortunately, even doing so does not prevent the application from crashing. Still getting the same error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should remove the `getApplicationContext()` from the User Class constructor because for json you can not write the context object.

```
User myUser= new User("a", "b", 2);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(myUser);
prefsEditor.putString(myUser.getUserPhone(), json);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

if you want to use the `getApplicationContext()` make another secondary 
 constructor. And assign the transient keyword of context in User class.

```
private transient Context context;
```

If you make a field in a Java class transient then GSON will ignore it in both serialization and deserialization

Comment: Ok, it wasn't just a Context issue, there were other member variables not used as parameters in the constructor and I didn't pay attention to them. Making them transient did the trick, so your answer was very helpful.

Comment: Thank you Gabriel.

Answer (score 0):

To convert your model or object into String by using Gson you have to follow below given steps :

1st Step: Make sure that Gson dependency is added to your app gradle file. ( if not added then add as given below. )

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

2nd Step: Your Model Class

```
public class ModelClass {

String name;
String number;

public ModelClass() {
}

public ModelClass(String name, String number, Context context) {
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
 }
}
```

3rd Step: Finally convert your model or object to String by using Gson

```
ModelClass modelClass=new ModelClass("abc","45465545",MainActivity.this); // here we pass three parameters to ModelClass. ( name, number and context )
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString=gson.toJson(modelClass);
```